# OPTIONS method instead of GET after adding authorization header

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I have an usb fingerprint scanner which is accessed by using REST on following port and ip: *http://127.0.0.1:30666/foh/UCBioAPI/devices* It works correctly in Postman as seen in screenshot below:

[image]

However I cannot get it to work with jQuery Ajax.

```
var url2 = 'http://127.0.0.1:30666/foh/UCBioAPI/devices';
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url2,
                headers: {
                    "authorization": "Basic " + btoa('user' + ":" + 'user'),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('done!');
                }, error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
```

What happens is this (device doesn't accept OPTIONS probably and is not modifiable):
[image]

[image]

The problem is I cannot change how the device works. The only thing I can modify is my javascript code. My server works in IIS 10 and is basically the same domain - localhost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are requesting 127.0.0.1 from localhost, since the browser thinks this is cross domain it makes an OPTIONS request first, and your server is denying the request. Change your server to allow cross domain or use localhost instead of an IP address

Comment: Try to make it "https" or change 127.0.0.1 to localhost.

Comment: _“The problem is I cannot change how the device works.”_ - then you _can not_ make this kind of client-side cross-domain request to it, simple as that.

Comment: Try to use `beforeSend` in your `jQuery` request, like this:  `beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " +btoa('user' + ":" + 'user'));
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postman is not sandboxed with CORS and skips it completely. A browser acts in a different way. It sends the data for CORS authentication before doing the actual request. The OPTIONS request is exactly that one. It contains origin, host and actual request type so the server can decide if it should accept it.

If you can't change the code on the device you are out of luck, it won't work.

Just in case, there is a good article about CORS:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Just to precise, CORS doesn't make sense in a Postman context as there is no Origin (url from which the request is done) for the request. It is like when you write an url directly in your browser, in opposite as requested from within a page (html link, form post, javascript call)

Answer (score -1):

Try `beforeSend` function instead of `headers`.

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('user' + ":" + 'user'));
}
```

Comment: its just another syntax for "headers: {}"